# Obtaining Access Token Server Side Instagram Graph Api V3

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

What I'm trying to achieve:
Fetch images from my own Instagram business account to display on a website using the Instagram graph api v3.3 by not obtaining a user access token from a client side Facebook SDK login modal because users just shouldn't be doing that to see a simple Instagram feed.

I have the permissions manage_pages and instagram_basic granted(gone through app review). I'm using app_id and app_secret as user access_token parameter value(which may not be the access token Instagram graph api is looking for) as when I tried to fetch any data there is an error message:
" #10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.'" However, I don't need the permission Page Public Content Access because I'm fetching images from my own account. This is also confirmed by the Facebook App Review support.

The query that is used to get the images is as follows:
`https://graph.facebook.com/${pageId}?fields=id&access_token=${accessToken}` 
My access token in this case is app_id|app_secret since I can't access the user access token.

The developer api guide "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started/" only shows a way to get user access token using the client side Facebook SDK login button which generates a user access token after a visiting user interacts with a modal that pops up to have them login. But again, a simple Instagram image gallery shouldn't require every user that visit the site to log in to their own Facebook account.

I have bugged the App Review support team at Facebook with no real answer. I couldn't join the Facebook developers support group as no one is approving my request to join and I've also tried my best to seek help from the facebook developers support team but I can't reach them. So I'm turning to Stack Overflow to ask if there is any way to display images from an Instagram Business Account without sticking a Facebook login SDK modal on the site.

Thanks so much.

EDIT: After reading @misorude's comment, I'm thinking would adding the Facebook login modal on the website and querying it by logging into my own Facebook account and then capturing *my own* user access token that is returned by the api and then use that access token for every susequent api calls to fetch images work?

Comment: app_id|app_secret is an _app_ access token, and you can not use that, because with that the API has no way of knowing you have access to the account, and it is _not_ just public access. You need to use a user access token - _yours_. And since you don’t want to expose your own token in client-side code, you need to do this whole thing on the server side to begin with.

Comment: @misorude Thanks for your reply! I am definitely trying to obtain a user access token server side but the getting started doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started/ only shows a way to obtain it from a Facebook Login modal. Do you know what are the steps to get a user access token server side? I am scowering the internet for a tutorial on this with no luck.

Comment: @misorude I guess my real issue here is that I'm not sure how to get  _my own_ user access token on the server.

Comment: Acquiring user access tokens requires user interaction, i.e. the login dialog. You can extend the token to be valid for up to 60 days though.